# Absolute singleton over multiple wars (share classloader)

Tags: java, jboss, singleton, classloader, war

I've found some information about this topic, but haven't found a good solution yet:

Let's say I have 3 projects:

- Core (java)
- FrontEnd (jsp and ember)
- WS (java)

Both the WS and the FrontEnd contain a maven dependency to Core.
In Core, there is a singleton SomeDao like these:

```
private static SomeDao _instance = null;

public static SomeDao getInstance() {
    if (_instance != null)
        return _instance;
    synchronized (SomeDao.class) {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new SomeDao();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

The application is hosted in JBoss WildFly and both the WS (java) and the FrontEnd (jsp) use SomeDao, but because of the different classloaders, there are two instantiations for SomeDao. SomeDao has his own cache, and thus, becomes out of sync after a while (WS <-> FrontEnd).

My questions:

- What is the best approach to force just one instantation (make a parent war, fuse the wars, use the same classloader, a maven solution, place Core as lib in JBoss, deploy Core as his own WAR in JBoss) and why?
- Is it possible to access the classloader of the other WAR in JBoss? If so, how?

Comment: To clarify: JBoss has 2 wars: FrontEnd and WS each with their own dependency to Core

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you:

> Because multiple classloaders are commonly used in many
>   situations—including servlet containers—you can wind up with multiple
>   singleton instances no matter how carefully you've implemented your
>   singleton classes. If you want to make sure the same classloader loads
>   your singletons, you must specify the classloader yourself; for
>   example:

```
private static Class getClass(String classname) 
                                         throws ClassNotFoundException {
      ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      if(classLoader == null)
         classLoader = Singleton.class.getClassLoader();
      return (classLoader.loadClass(classname));
   }
}
```

Source: [Simply Singleton - JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2)